# iOS Developing: Use Mail.app icons in custom application

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, interface-builder

I'm building an application with messaging ability. I would like to use some of the icons of Apple's Mail.app in my application (for example the inbox icon). Is this possible and allowed? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not allowed. Find free custom icons, there are tonns of them over the internet.